# QGIS 2.18 Las Palmas Error Screen upon project opening. Win 10

Tags: installation, qgis-2.18, qgis-cloud

I am working on a trail map for a Non-Profit.  Created a few maps last couple of years with previous versions of QGIS and just updated to 2.18.  Running a Windows 10 OS.

QGIS loads fine, but when project starts to load get pop up error message with cryptic login requirement with unknown user and password already in place.  Of course this is Not valid and will not clear.  I do not know for sure what site it is trying to log in to.  Program will not load and cycles back to error message.

To the best of my ability it appeared to be trying to access the qgiscloud.com.  I did change the default password being displayed with my qgis cloud password to no avail.  Have attached image of error message.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This message is asking you to provide credentials to an external database connection.  The errors indicate that QGIS was not able to establish a connection to this database, due to a connection timeout.

Click on **Cancel** to skip past this and get back into the interface.  It is possible that many different connections may be failing consecutively, each generating its own popup, which may give the appearance of the same window appearing again and again.  Look at the things writting in the **Realm** field at the top - they will probably appear different with each new window.

To stop this from happening in the future,

Go to the **Browser Panel** and find the offending connections (looks like a little brown fork, and could be in any one of the sections highlighted in red, but I would guess that in your case it is in the **PostGIS** section):

[image]

Right click on it, and either **Edit** it and update the connection parameters, or **Delete** it:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it turns out a number of layers were not loading and that canceling eventually cleared the cache of messages.  (This took some time on some layers)  Eventually this came to a end and pulled up the Handle bad layer menu.

None of the layers were originally pointing to external databases and this caused my confusion as to what was trying to load.  These were *.shp files I had created in the previous version.  The problem seems to have appeared because I installed the new version of QGIS on to a different hard drive so that location of the SHP location lost.  Pointing to the correct location solved the problem.